# Editing ODC file in C#

Tags: c#, html, xml, xml-namespaces

I am trying to edit an .odc file in c# i thought it would be simple because its just xml but when i run it and it comes to Load the document `xmlDoc.Load("THEFILE.odc")` it gives me an error:

'Content-Type' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 5, position 18.
And that is i figure talking about Line 5 position 18 of the doc itself which is:

```
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/x-ms-odc; charset=utf-8">
```

the file is below.  it is an odc file.  I need to go through the connection properties and change the ConnectionString.  Thanks in advace

```
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/x-ms-odc; charset=utf-8">
<meta name=ProgId content=ODC.Table>
<meta name=SourceType content=OLEDB>
<title>Title</title>
<xml id=docprops><o:DocumentProperties
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <odc:Connection odc:Type="OLEDB">
   <odc:ConnectionString>"ConnectionString"</odc:ConnectionString>
   <odc:CommandType>Table</odc:CommandType>
   <odc:CommandText>"CommandText"</odc:CommandText>
   <odc:SSOApplicationID>testReport</odc:SSOApplicationID>
   <odc:CredentialsMethod>Stored</odc:CredentialsMethod>
  </odc:Connection>
 </odc:OfficeDataConnection>
</xml>
<style>
<!--
    .ODCDataSource
    {
    behavior: url(dataconn.htc);
    }
-->
</style>

</head>
```

Theres more to the file itself but above is the xml which im trying to edit.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your .ODC file looks like XML but it's not. It doesn't respect some XML rules.
For instance the meta tags are not closed.

`<meta name=ProgId content=ODC.Table>`

should be

`<meta name="ProgId" content="ODC.Table"/>` (notice the quotes and slash added)

And for the first error for Content-Type; it should be :

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/x-ms-odc; charset=utf-8"/>`
(Content-Type need to be surrounded with quotes (or single quotes)).

I'd suggest you to load directly your .ODC file with [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) or use some cleansing tool before loading it.

Comment: i didnt create this odc file. it was made by excel for me i am actually trying to create a feature in sharepoint so that when i activate the feature it changes the connection string accordingly.  now i will be deploying to different servers and there are alot of these odc files in the connection library.  any other way which will be efficient? and i will also look into the link you gave me.  Thanks alot

also i just started reading this file as text using streamreader.  and i am thinkin about using that to change watever i need wat you think about that?

Comment: @Faizych use HTML Agility Pack to change what ever you need. This pack is enable to read bad formed (x)HTML like .ODC files. You'll advance faster in your work by using it.