# Connect with Office Data Connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-office

I have an Excel .odc file which defines an OLEDB connection like so:

> Provider=MSOLAP.5;
> Integrated Security=SSPI;
> Persist Security Info=True;
> User ID="";
> Initial Catalog="";
> Data Source=xxx.xxx.com\tabular;
> Location=xxx.xxx.com\tabular;
> MDX Compatibility=1;
> Safety Options=2;
> MDX Missing Member Mode=Error

Is it possible for me to open the database using SqlConnection in C# using this?

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831843/connect-with-oledbconnection

Comment: Is this an Excel Add-In, or a stand-alone program? Do you expect to show the results in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built into .Net outside of Office Interop (actually opening an instance of Excel), an Office Add-In (Excel is already opened, and the code runs as a macro), or [Reporting  Services + Sharepoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326418.aspx)  to use `*.odc`  files to connect to a database. You will have to write your own code to open the file, parse the values out for a connection string, and use that string to connect to a database.

When you go to write this code, be careful: ODC is [not-quite valid XML.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379857/editing-odc-file-in-c-sharp)